# Installing library from git in python - ImportError: Bad git executable

Tags: git

I want to install FacebookPostsScraper from git repository: https://github.com/adeoy/FacebookPostsScraper

I'm using this code:

```
import git
git clone https://github.com/adeoy/FacebookPostsScraper.git
```

and I get the following error when importing git:

> ImportError: Bad git executable.
>
> The git executable must be specified in one of the following ways:
>
> - be included in your $PATH
> - be set via $GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE
> - explicitly set via git.refresh()

- OS: Windows 10
- Python 3.7, Spyder
- GitHub desktop 2.6.0 installed

I'm looking for help in installing FacebookPostsScraper this way or another.

Answer (score 0):

If you're following the installation instructions, you should just be running

```
git clone https://github.com/adeoy/FacebookPostsScraper.git
```

on the command line (e.g. in git shell) rather than within a Python program. Then you would run the `pip` command to install the dependencies - from within that directory (folder).